# How to prove this inequality if $\|x_i\|=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How to prove that for given $k\geq 1$, if $\|x_i\|=1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$, $\alpha_1\neq0$ and $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|\geq |\lambda_3|\geq\dots\geq |\lambda_n|$, then

\begin{equation}
\|\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^k x_i \|_2 \leq \left\lvert\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right\rvert^k\left(\sum_{i=2}^n \left(\frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}

This is a convergence analysis of the power method.

[image]

Comment: You are missing some information about $k$. Is it real, or integer, positive only, greater than 1?

Comment: Sorry. $k\geq 1$ and is an integer.

Comment: The result holds for all $k \geq 1$ iff it holds for $k=1$.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ orthonormal, else there might be a factor $\sqrt{n-1}$ missing.

Comment: They are just L.i.

Comment: Start from [Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the text "Numerical Mathematics" where I found the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text does not make much sense. One can always normalize the generalized eigenvectors.

$\|\sum c_ix_i\|$ will be close to $|\sum c_i|$ if the $x_i$ are almost equal, $\sqrt{\sum |c_i|^2}$ is usually much smaller.

It appears that the Euclidean norm is for the coordinates in the eigen-basis, then the question-critical inequality is the Pythagorean identity.

In general you can get
$$
\|\sum_{i=2..n}c_ix_i\|\le \sum_{i=2..n}|c_i|\|x_i\|\le\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{\sum_{i=2..n} |c_i|^2},
$$
the last by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. This is also sufficient for the convergence proof.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.